# Create Array newline and add values into multidimensional Array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a set of values as a string, like so:

```
MyCustomProductID1
MyCustomProductID2
```

Then I proceed to create an array out of these values with `explode( "\n", $myProductIdString)`

Now I have additional data (strings) that I want to combine with the value from my first array. I want that simple array into a multidimensional one:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => MyCustomProductID1
            [url] => http://example.com/MyCustomProductID1.jpg
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => MyCustomProductID2
            [url] => http://example.com/MyCustomProductID2.jpg
        )

)
```

How do I get that first array into a multidimensional one and push data along with it?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of direct assigning values to array use loop-

```
<?php
$str = "MyCustomProductID1
MyCustomProductID2";

$arr = explode("\n", $str);

$result = [];

$url_array = ["http://example.com/MyCustomProductID1.jpg", "http://example.com/MyCustomProductID2.jpg"];

for($i=0;$i<count($arr);$i++){
    $result[$i]['id'] = $arr[$i];
    $result[$i]['url'] =    $url_array[$i];
}

print_r($result);
?>
```